# Convert alphanumeric varchar to int

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using this script

```
select * from mxiv_sentries where 
attrname='mskeyvalue' and mskey in
(select mskey from mxiv_sentries where attrname='MXREF_MX_PRIVILEGE' and searchvalue='672081'
and mskey not in
(select Default_login from mxman_rt_u.VPN))
```

these are two different tables where Default_login is alphanumeric and varchar and mskey is number in INT. So when i execute this script i end up with error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'A15271' to data type int.

Can you please suggest how to get proper results 
Thanks

Comment: How are you expecting anyone to convert something that is not a number to a number?  Are there rules that we can use to determine how to convert?

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT YOUR QUESTION. WE'RE NOT BLIND.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to downvote the poor guy for his ignorance, though...

Answer (score 5):

You obviously have a value of `'A15271'` in the `Default_Login` field in the `VPN` table.

If this is a `varchar`, you need to either

- (preferably) **NOT COMPARE IT TO NUMERICS** since, you know, they are different data types and not equivalent
- or (less preferably) `CAST` the `int` as a `Varchar` before the comparison.  This will have some overhead and will likely make your indexes moot, but in a query like this with a structure like this indexes may not even exist.